# Flutter, How to make a unit test on a Widget that contain AppLocalization (multilingual)?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing, localization, multilingual

I am trying to make a simple test on my HistoryPage widget, here it is :

```
class HistoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HistoryPageState createState() => _HistoryPageState();
}

class _HistoryPageState extends State<HistoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.historyPageTitle),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the unit test for that widget :

```
  group('UI TESTS', () {
    Widget makeTesteableWidget({required Widget child}) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: child,
      );
    }

    testWidgets('History page', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // Create the widget by telling the tester to build it.
      final widget = makeTesteableWidget(
        child: HistoryPage(),
      );

      await tester.pumpWidget(widget);

      expect(true, true);
    });
  });
```

Here is the exception when I run the test :

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building HistoryPage(dirty, dependencies:
[_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#ca13b]], state: _HistoryPageState#b1cad):
Null check operator used on a null value

If I replace the AppBar title like this :

```
appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Simple title'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
```

The test is working... But I don't know how to manage this line to not throw this exception...

```
title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.historyPageTitle),
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

It's work for me :)

```dart
  Future<AppLocalizations> getLocalizationsUnderTests(
    WidgetTester t,
  ) async {
    late AppLocalizations result;
    await t.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: const <LocalizationsDelegate>[
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
        locale: const Locale('en'),
        home: Material(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              result = AppLocalizations.of(context);
              debugPrint('[DEBUG]: locale: $result');

              // The builder function must return a widget.
              return const Placeholder();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    await t.pumpAndSettle();
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue ! In the test, in the MaterialApp I just called (like in the main) the localizations, like this :

```
group('UI TESTS', () {
    Widget makeTesteableWidget({required Widget child}) {
      return MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', ''),
          // English, no country code
          const Locale('fr', ''),
          // French, no country code
          const Locale('de', ''),
          // German, no country code
          // const Locale('gsw', ''), // Swiss German Alemannic Alsatian, no country code
          const Locale('it', ''),
          // Italian, no country code
        ],
        home: child,
      );
    }

    testWidgets('History page', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // Create the widget by telling the tester to build it.
      final widget = makeTesteableWidget(
        child: LoginPage(),
      );

      await tester.pumpWidget(widget);

      expect(true, true);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Cool. I have this problem as well that we put localize in the widget based on conditions. Let me test it out. Thanks

Comment: I tried this approach since was similar to the one I implemented myself but did not work out. This post clarified things for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862833/flutter-how-to-test-localized-widgets. Basically what you need to do is provide a context by creating a widget instead of a simple return of a widget.